# display all likes from a row in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code
this part is row1 i need to count every like and also count neutral from this inputs and display the number of likes and neutrals separately

```
    <tr>
          <td>1.</td> 
          <td style="border-right: 1px solid;"><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Like" <?php if($answer1=="Like") echo "checked"?> disabled></td> 
          <td style="border-right: 1px solid;"><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Neutral" <?php if($answer1=="1Neutral") echo "checked"?> disabled></td> 
          <td style="border-right: 1px solid;"><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Dislike" <?php if($answer1=="1Dislike") echo "checked"?> disabled></td> 

          <td>13.</td>
          <td style="border-right: 1px solid;"><input type="radio" name="answer13" value="Like"<?php if($answer13=="Like") echo "checked"?> disabled></td> <!--name="q1"-->
          <td style="border-right: 1px solid;"><input type="radio" name="answer13" value="Neutral" <?php if($answer13=="Neutral") echo "checked"?> disabled></td> 
          <td style="border-right: 1px solid;"><input type="radio" name="answer13" value="Dislike" <?php if($answer13=="Dislike") echo "checked"?> disabled></td> 

          <td>25.</td>
          <td style="border-right: 1px solid;"><input type="radio" name="answer25" value="Like" <?php if($answer25=="Like") echo "checked"?> disabled></td> 
          <td style="border-right: 1px solid;"><input type="radio" name="answer25" value="Neutral" <?php if($answer25=="Neutral") echo "checked"?> disabled></td> 
          <td style="border-right: 1px solid;"><input type="radio" name="answer25" value="Dislike" <?php if($answer25=="Dislike") echo "checked"?> disabled></td> 



          <td style="border-left: 1px solid">R1</td>
```

and this is my if statement

```
    <?php
            $Like = null;
            $Neutral = null;
            $dislike = null;

            $valid = true;

                 if ($answer1 == 'Like') {
                $Like = 'answer 1 L';
                $valid = true;
                }
                  if ($answer1 == 'Neutral') {
                    $Neutral = 'answer 1 N';
                    $valid = true;
                  }

                    if ($answer13 == 'Like') {
                        $Like = '2';
                        $valid = true;
                      }
                        elseif ($answer13 == 'Neutral') {
                            $Neutral = 'answer13 N';
                            $valid = true;
                                }

                            if ($answer25 == 'Like') {
                              $Like = 'answer25 L';
                              $valid = true;
                            }
                              elseif ($answer25 == 'Neutral') {
                                $Neutral = 'answer 25 N';
                                $valid = true;
                              }

          ?>


          <td><?php echo $Like ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $Neutral ?></td>
```

What i need to do is echo every Like from $Like and Neutral from $Neutral.. I don't know if this is the proper way to do this I'm open for suggestions :)

Comment: If you are getting your info from a mysql table, there are much better ways of doing this. Show your table schema and a few rows of the table. Minor suggestion, use proper indenting on your code to make it more readable. The first 3 if's should be at the same indent level (not trying to be too picky, but since you're new, just a helpful suggestion).

Comment: No way other people can understand what you are doing. Explain.

Comment: Oh boy some mystery is going on here. Can you please reformulate what you're trying to do? (Keep in mind people here don't know your context). 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask